# Laravel 5.8: Interface is not instantiable

Tags: php, laravel, interface, repository

I know that this question was asked so many times, but none of answers helped me.
I'm getting exception in Laravel 5.8:

```
Target [App\Repositories\Category\CategoryRepositoryInterface] is not instantiable while building [App\Http\Controllers\Admin\CategoryController, App\Services\CategoryServices].
```

What I've done without success:
Register App\Providers\RepositoryServiceProvider in providers
Structure:

```
app
  - Repositories
    - CategoryRepository.php
    - CategoryRepositoryInterface.php
  - Models
    - CategoryModel.php
  - Providers
    - RepositoryServiceProvider.php
  - Services
    - CategoryService.php
```

CategoryRepositoryInterface.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Repositories\Category;


interface CategoryRepositoryInterface
{
    public function show();
}
```

CategoryRepository.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Repositories\Category;

use App\Models\CategoryModel;
// use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Repositories\Category\CategoryRepositoryInterface;

class CategoryRepository implements CategoryRepositoryInterface
{
    const TABLE = 'category';
    private $model;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->model = new CategoryModel();
    }

    public function show()
    {
        return $this->model->all();
    }
}
```

RepositoryServiceProvider.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Repositories\Category\CategoryRepository;
use App\Repositories\Category\CategoryRepositoryInterface;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class RepositoryServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot() {}

    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton(CategoryRepositoryInterface::class, CategoryRepository::class);
    }
}
```

CategoryController.php:

```
class CategoryController extends Controller
{

    private $categoryServices;

    function __construct(categoryServices $categoryServices)
    {
        $this->categoryServices = $categoryServices;
        // dd($categoryServices);
    }

    public function index()
    {
        try {
            $category = $this->categoryServices->index();
            return view('AdminStore.pages.categorys.cate_list', compact('category'));
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            abort('500');
        }
    }
```

composer.json:

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "App\\Models\\": "app/Models/",
            "App\\Repositories\\": "app/Repositories/"
        },
```

Comment: It says `Repositoties` in your config - is this an actual typo or just an error in the question?

Comment: @El_Vanja it is an typo, I fixed it